# Is there a venue to publish negative results in AI/ML domain?

Tags: research, academia

Negative results occur frequently in AI/ML research (and perhaps in other domains too). Most of the time, these results are not published. This is mostly because your typical AI/ML conference doesn't accept such papers.

However, are there any venues to publish these results?  I believe these results can be still useful to look at before you delve into a certain project so that you'd at least know what approaches don't work.

As an example venue, there seems to be [PerFail workshop](https://perfail-workshop.github.io/2022/) from the pervasive computing domain. So, is there something similar for AI/ML?

Answer (score 1):

This workshop that has been at NeurIPS for several years is for things you think aught to work, but don't:
https://i-cant-believe-its-not-better.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Such results should probably be put on arXiv. It's moderated, but there's no peer-review process, so if your goal is to just make useful information available, then this is your best bet.